# Image not displaying in browser in Node project

Tags: html, css, node.js, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code. I downloaded an image from the internet, after which I put in the directory of my Node project. I then changed the name of the image, wrote `<img src = "file_2.jpeg">` and opened it my browser. I did not see the aforementioned image.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your comments and question, it seems you have unnecessary whitespace around the `src` attribute. I am unsure if this was an accident while writing your question, but if not, change `<img src = "file_2.jpeg">` to `<img src="file_2.jpeg">`.

This brings me to the next possibility: is the filepath correct? I would need to know your project root and filepath in order to tell you exactly what to input, however, try changing `<img src="file_2.jpeg">` to `<img src="file:///project-root/path-to-file/file_2.jpeg">`.

If neither of these fix your problem, I am unsure as to any other reason why the image would not display.

Ask yourself questions such as this, and

> Is there any styling that could affect my image?

this.

> Is the filename the same in my `src` as it is in my image's directory?

Also make sure to check through your code until you're absolutely sure that there is no obvious solution.

In this example, markup should look something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="document-root/path-to-file/file_2.jpeg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for me to help if I could see your file path, but I can try. Say the image was 'picture.png', and it was in a folder call 'Folder', with a file called 'index.html', which had in the body tag this code:

```
<img src="picture.png" alt="awesome picture">
```

Then it should work. If it was in a sub-directory called 'SubFolder then you would do for the src: 'SubFolder/picture.png'. Thats all I can think of. If you show me your file path, I can help more.
Would the code look something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title Here</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="file_2.jpeg">
</body>
</html>
```

If so, I can't find anything wrong.

Comment: I understand it  but I dont see picture in browser

Comment: <img src="relative path of picture"> it does not work

Comment: c:\Users\Администратор\Documents\localDataBase\client.html, C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\localDataBase\file_2.jpeg -photo, localDataBase - my project, <img src = "file2.jpeg"> -this is  some code  from html file - \client.html

Comment: Did you try doing file_2.jpeg ?

Comment: <img src = "file_2.jpeg"> sorry, but I wrote wrong here

Comment: may be some  problems with vs code? What do you think about it?

Comment: I think that probably is the problem now, but I've only used vs once. I'll research your problem for you, and relay what I find.